# NextJS Images replaces each other

Tags: django, typescript, image, next.js, tailwind-css

I got so strange problem with NextJS Images. I use Django as my backend server and fetching data and Image URLs from Django in my NextJS project. Look

```
import React, { FC, Suspense } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Loader from '../Loader';

interface ProducerClientProps {}

async function getProducers() {
  let res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/market/producers`);
  return res.json();
}

const ProducerClient: FC<ProducerClientProps> = async ({}) => {
  const data = await getProducers();
  return (
    <aside className="min-w-max flex flex-col gap-5">
      <div className="grid grid-cols-2">
        {data.map((producer: Producer) => (
          <div className="flex justify-center">
            <Link
              href={`/producers/${producer.slug}`}
              className="flex items-center"
            >
              <div className="hover:scale-105 transition-transform duration-100 p-5">
                <Image
                  src={producer.image === null ? '/' : producer.image}
                  alt={producer.title}
                  width={80}
                  height={80}
                  style={{ objectFit: 'contain' }}
                />
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </aside>
  );
};

export default ProducerClient;
```

So in this code my Images replaces each other sometimes and even doubles. Like if I have Image_1.png, so I could see Image_1.png instead of Image_2.png in mapped data. Feels like observer effect, because when I make breakpoints in DevTools - everything works fine.

[Optimized Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLJFa.png)

[Unoptimized Image (how it should look)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqwhp.png)

Then I have Carousel component.

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';
import Loader from '../Loader';

interface CarouselProps {
  data: NewsImages[];
}

const Carousel: FC<CarouselProps> = ({ data: slides }) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const goToNext = () => {
    const isLastSlide = currentIndex === slides.length - 1;
    const newIndex = isLastSlide ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
    setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
  };

  const goToSlide = (slideIndex: number) => {
    setCurrentIndex(slideIndex);
  };

  if (!slides || slides.length === 0) {
    // Возвращаем загрузчик или пустой контейнер, если данные отсутствуют
    return <Loader />;
  }

  return (
    <section className="h-full relative flex flex-col gap-5 items-center z-0">
      <div onClick={goToNext} className="cursor-pointer w-full">
        <Image
          src={`${slides[currentIndex].image}`}
          alt={slides[currentIndex].title}
          width={1060}
          height={320}
          style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }}
          className="rounded-lg h-[320px]"
          unoptimized
        />
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-center gap-2">
        {slides.map((slide: any, slideIndex: any) => (
          <div key={slideIndex} onClick={() => goToSlide(slideIndex)}>
            <div
              className={`h-2 rounded-full cursor-pointer ${
                slideIndex === currentIndex
                  ? 'bg-black w-4 transition-all duration-300'
                  : 'bg-gray w-2'
              }`}
            ></div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

And if Image != unoptimized, then Images for ProducerClient can be shown in Carousel!

I tried to delete .next folder, clear cache. But nothing helps, only looking into breakpoints in DevTools on data fetching helps, but it's not how website should work of course. And when I make responsive window in DevTools - I see Image being replaced more often.